# Detailed QueryTables Error Handling

Tags: sql, excel, vba, error-handling

Good Afternoon,

I am looking for a way to handle QueryTable Errors. I have looked at other questions on google and stackoverflow, however they do not appear to answer the specific question i am trying to ask.

Basically, is there a way to determine what the specific error was when handling a QueryTables error?

Code:

```
On Error Goto queryError

With Activesheet.QueryTables...

....
End With


queryError:
    Msgbox("There was an error with the QueryTables. The reason for the error was: " & myError)
```

Is there a way to set myError to give more details specific to what the problem was, even if it means selecting some sort of status code? eg

```
QueryTables.StatusCode...
```

or something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try - `Err.Number` and `Err.Description`

Comment: Look at the `Select Case` in the answer below to see how to use `Err.Number` in your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How to handle errors:**

Excel VBA doesn't support`Try Catch Finally`. Instead, it uses `On Error GoTo`

For full control over error-handling in Excel you must use labels (which always end in a colon).

In this example, the two labels are:

- *tryAgain:*
- *queryError:*

Assume that the Query Table being created is from a text file that looks something like:

[image: Text File]

When you first run the routine, the user is prompted for three inputs:

- Filepath
- New Table Name
- Cell (i.e. Range) to paste into

[image: Input Box]

If an error occurs on any of these inputs, the code will immediately go to the label *queryError:*

So, say the user didn't enter in a valid filepath, it would look something like this:

[image: Error Message]

If the user clicks Yes (to try again), then `Resume tryAgain` will take the code back up to that label and go through it all over.

Pay attention to the `Select Case` at the end.  This is how you can control how you want to handle specific errors.

**Here is the code to paste in a module:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub CreateQueryTable()

    'Assign values to these variables by prompting user with Input Boxes
    Dim filepath As String
    Dim qryTableName As String
    Dim startCellForTable As Range

    'These variables are used in the error handling prompts
    Dim Msg As String
    Dim Ans As Integer

    'If an error occurs, code will go to the label `queryError:`
    On Error GoTo queryError


tryAgain:

    'Prompt user for the filename of the .txt file to use as QueryTable Source
    filepath = InputBox("Please enter filepath of text file to use as the source")

    'Prompt user to name the new Query Table
    qryTableName = InputBox("Please enter name of Query Table")

    'Prompt user for the cell to put table at
    Set startCellForTable = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please select a cell where you would like to paste the table to", Type:=8)


    'If user hits OK, check to see that they at least put something as a value
    If filepath <> "" And qryTableName <> "" And startCellForTable <> "" Then

        'format filepath variable so can pass it as argument to QueryTables.Add
        'Trim any leading or trailing spaces from qryTableName
        filepath = "TEXT;" & filepath
        qryTableName = Trim(qryTableName)

    End If

    'Create QueryTable at Range("A1")
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=filepath, Destination:=Range(startCellForTable.Address))
        .Name = qryTableName
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With

    'If there are no errors, exit the procedure (so the `queryError:` code won't execute)
    Exit Sub


queryError:

    Msg = ""

    'Say that an error occured
    Msg = Msg & "An error occurred with the Query Table. " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine

    'Use Excel's built-in Error object (named `Err`) to show error number and description of error
    Msg = Msg & Err.Number & ": " & Error(Err.Number) & vbNewLine & vbNewLine

    Select Case Err.Number

        'Type mismatch
        Case 13


        'Object required
        Case 424

            Msg = Msg & vbNewLine & "Please check that a valid range was selected" & vbNewLine

        'Application defined or Object defined error
        Case 1004

            Msg = Msg & vbNewLine & "Please check that this filepath is correct: " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & filepath & vbNewLine

        Case Else


    End Select


    'Prompt user to Try Again
    Msg = Msg & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Try again?"

    Ans = MsgBox(Msg, vbYesNo + vbCritical)

    'If user says Yes, clear the error, and resume execution of code at label `TryAgain:`
    If Ans = vbYes Then Resume tryAgain


End Sub
```